# Xamarin ModernHTTPClient Unhandled exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httpclient, lan

I'm trying to get the source of a website on my local network, but unfortunately all it gives is an unhandled exception while using this code. I've tried Webclient and HTTPWebRequest, both gave a somewhat same exception.. Anyone that could help??

```
public async void GetURL(ToggleButton tbtn)
    {

            string url = "http://192.168.1.180"
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            var _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var _cancelToken = _cancelTokenSource.Token;
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, _cancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Besides, the code works while testing sites like Google, so the only explanation to me is that it fails on LAN networks.. must be some kind of solution to it.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding a try/catch to catch the exception?

Comment: Yes. But when implementing the try/catch, it would just always end up in the catch

Comment: Yes, but that will allow you to see the specific exception that is causing this

Comment: Ah, you meant it that way.. The error it seems to reference to is:

`unexpected end of stream on Connection{192.168.1.180:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=192.168.1.180 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)`

Comment: What is the encoding format of your website on local network?

Comment: You can use fiddler to catch the log when request from your website, and maybe share the log and the exception here.